# Okio Throttler integration with OkHttp

Tags: okhttp, okio

My team is suffering from this [issue](https://github.com/slackapi/python-slack-sdk/issues/1165) with slack integration to upload files, so following the comments in that issue I would like to throttle the requests in our Kotlin implementation.

I am trying to integrate Okio [Throttler](https://square.github.io/okio/3.x/okio/okio/okio/-throttler/index.html) within an OkHttp interceptor, so I have the setup:

```
val client = OkHttpClient.Builder()
            .retryOnConnectionFailure(false)
            .addInterceptor { chain ->
                val request = chain.request()
                val originalRequestBody = request.body
                val newRequest = if (originalRequestBody != null) {
                    val wrappedRequestBody = ThrottledRequestBody(originalRequestBody)
                    request.newBuilder()
                        .method(request.method, wrappedRequestBody)
                        .build()
                } else {
                    request
                }
                chain.proceed(newRequest)
            }
            .build()
```

```kotlin
class ThrottledRequestBody(private val delegate: RequestBody) : RequestBody() {
    private val throttler = Throttler().apply {
        bytesPerSecond(1024, 1024 * 4, 1024 * 8)
    }


    override fun contentType(): MediaType? {
        return delegate.contentType()
    }

    override fun writeTo(sink: BufferedSink) {
        delegate.writeTo(throttler.sink(sink).buffer())
    }
}
```

It seems `throttler.sink` returns a `Sink`, but a `BufferedSink` is required to the method `delegate.writeTo`, so I called `buffer()` to get that `BufferedSink`.
Am I doing it wrong ? Is the call for `.buffer()` breaking the integration?

Answer (score 3):

It's almost perfect. You just need to flush the buffer when you're done otherwise it'll finish with a few bytes inside.

```
override fun writeTo(sink: BufferedSink) {
  throttler.sink(sink).buffer().use {
    delegate.writeTo(it)
  }
}
```